# YouTube maxresdefault.jpg is not being generated

Tags: youtube

We have a number of videos that we upload to YouTube and we pull and display on our site the maxresdefault.jpg image for each video.

For some reason there are some videos where the maxresdefault.jpg is not created, it just shows a gray image (the image when there is no thumbnail). These videos do have thumbnails (as the other resolutions work).

What steps can I take to troubleshoot?